Image not loading in HTML page when trying to change using GetElementByID method
I am attempting to write an simple function in an HTML page which displays the image and there are few buttons which change the image I have used the "document.getElementById('myImage').src= " command to change it but there is no image shows after I click the image. The same image is loading properly using the  tag. The same button works if I use a link direct taken from google. Below I have pasted the code. Any suggestions are appreciated.
<!IDOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<h2> This page shows changing emotions using various buttons </h2>

<img id = "image" src = "path\angry.jpg" style = "width:100px">

<button onclick = 'document.getElementById("image").src = "path\envy.jpg"'>Envy</button>
<button onclick = 'document.getElementById("image").src = "path\angry.jpg"'>Angry</button>
<button onclick = 'document.getElementById("image").src = "path\sad.jpg"'>Sad</button>
<button onclick = 'document.getElementById("image").src = "path\embarassed.jpg"'>Embarassed</button>
<button onclick = 'document.getElementById("image").src = "path\happy.jpg"'>Happy</button>
<button onclick = 'document.getElementById("image").src = "path\anxiety.jpg"'>Anxiety</button>


</body>
</html>


Tried links from Google it works but local images does not work in the on click function Thank you!

Have you tried using pathnames with "/" instead of ""?

The issue you're encountering is likely due to the backslashes () used in the file paths. In HTML and JavaScript, file paths should use forward slashes (/). Backslashes are not valid path separators in URLs.
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<h2> This page shows changing emotions using various buttons </h2>

<img id="image" src="path/angry.jpg" style="width:100px">

<button onclick='document.getElementById("image").src = "path/envy.jpg"'>Envy</button>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("image").src = "path/angry.jpg"'>Angry</button>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("image").src = "path/sad.jpg"'>Sad</button>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("image").src = "path/embarrassed.jpg"'>Embarrassed</button>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("image").src = "path/happy.jpg"'>Happy</button>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("image").src = "path/anxiety.jpg"'>Anxiety</button>

</body>
</html>


Don't use inline event handlers. Details are commented in the example.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    img {
      display: block;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      margin: 20px auto;
      cursor: pointer
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/bBGX3Sq/static.gif">
  <script>
    // Assign a counter outside of function
    let i = 0;
    // Have the URLs of the the images in an array
    const pix = [
      "https://i.ibb.co/c1PtcM7/matrix1.gif",
      "https://i.ibb.co/FHRS8Gx/stars.gif",
      "https://i.ibb.co/bBGX3Sq/static.gif"
    ];
    // This is the callback function that will be invoked at every click
    function changeSrc(e) {
      // Increment the counter
      i++;
      // If the count equals to or exceeds the number of URLs in pix array...
      if (i >= pix.length) {
        // Reset the counter back to 0
        i = 0;
      }
      // Change the src of the <img> to the URL at the index of "i" in array pix
      this.src = pix[i];
    }

    document.querySelector("img").onclick = changeSrc;
  </script>
</body>

</html>



